# Gibberish in read() buffer?

Tags: c, ruby

I am new to C, and so I am completely confused by the following behavior. Using `pipe()` and `fork()` I am reading the output of the following trivial ruby program:

```
puts "success"
```

via a call to the read function in C:

```
n = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
printf("received: %s", readbuffer);
```

However, `printf` is printing a bunch of those 'unrecognised character' symbols (like the question mark in a diamond) to the console. Furthermore, doing a comparison like:

```
    if (strcmp(readbuffer, "success") == 0)
    {
        /* do something */
    }
```

fails. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Declarations as requested. I have no idea about memsetting, my first day in C.

```
int fd[2], in;
pid_t pid;
char readbuffer[6];
```

Edit:

The answer by 'mu is too short' also solves the problem. The consensus seems to be that using `memset` is overkill. I am a novice C programmer so I will have to believe the commentors' opinions. This is, however, argumentum ad populum and mu is too short may indeed be more in the right. In any case, I recommend a reading of both answers as any 'overkill' is probably still trivially so.

Comment: Did you `memset` the buffer with `0` before using it? If you didn't then the buffer is not null terminated and will give you garbage values.

Comment: Declare readbuffer static or global and it will be zero-initialized.

Comment: please show the declarations of readbuffer and fd

Comment: edited with the declarations.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `read()` for errors?

Comment: `read()` does not seem to be giving any errors. It is returning 0.

Comment: If `read()` is returning 0, there's nothing to read.. maybe something's not setup right with the pipes?

Comment: A return value of zero indicates end of file; are you sure data are written by the time you're trying to read?

Comment: Everything looks good to me, I am using the guide here: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html for pipes. I will continue to fiddle...

Comment: There was indeed an additional issue with the pipes. Switching to using `popen()` resolved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your buffer isn't big enough to hold the text you're reading, and you don't ensure it's null terminated.

But using `memset()` to zero the entire buffer before each read is unnecessary; you just need to ensure that there's a null at the end of data you've read (and make your buffer bigger of course).

If you make `readbuffer` at least 9 characters long, and replace:

```
n = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
```

..with..

```
n = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer) - 1);
readbuffer[n] = '\0';
```

..then that should do it (though you should ideally check that `n` is >= 0 to make sure the `read()` succeeded).  Specifying one less than the size of the read buffer ensures that `readbuffer[n]` won't overrun (but if `read()` failed it could underrun).

Then you'll just have to deal with the linefeed at the end.

This also assumes that the entire string is read in one read call.  It's likely in this case, but often when using read its necessary to concatenate multiple reads until you've read enough of the data.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, you won't have a null terminator on `readbuffer` so it isn't really a C string. You could do this:

```
#include <string.h>

/* ... */

memset(readbuffer, 0, sizeof(readbuffer));
n = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer) - 1);
```

That will give you a proper null terminated string. But, if you actually want a string of length 6, then change the declaration of `readbuffer` to:

```
char readbuffer[7];
```

If you only need your `readbuffer` once, you could say:

```
char readbuffer[7] = { 0 };
```

to initialize it to all zeros. However, if you're doing the `read` in a loop then you'll want to `memset(readbuffer, 0, sizeof(readbuffer))` before each `read` to make sure you don't end up with any leftover data from the last step.

C won't automatically initialize a local variable, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: This indeed gets rid of the nonsense characters, however now the output is blank... I do know there is no error in receiving the text from ruby, as by changing 'success' to say, 'failure' and neglecting memset I can get variety of nonsense.

Comment: The `memset` is overkill. You can just write a single terminator after the data read, or you can use `"%.*s"` to output the data without needing termination.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your line:

```
puts "success"
```

will output (in C-terms)

```
success\n\0
```

which I count as 9 characters.

You declared `readbuffer` as only 6.  The previous answer only upped it to 7.

Comment: The 6 was a typo. I originally had 7 which, as you point out, is still too few. I have upped this number, thanks.